# How to export saved user credentials for WPA2 Enterprise AES

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, netsh

need help exporting the username and password.
I tried running this:

```
netsh wlan export profile name="mywifiname" folder="C:\users\admin\desktop\" key=clear
```

but it does not seem to export the username and password. just the certificate.

We are deploying it via MDT. Need a way to import saved wireless profiles with the user credentials in it.
That way, when we import the save profile, we don't have to manually enter the username and password.

Any suggestions how to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by certificate, it should output an xml file. I wasn't aware that there was a username, the usual entries would be the SSID and Security Key, (password). In that file it should have your `<SSIDConfig>` `<SSID>` `<name>` and `<MSM>` `<security>` `<sharedKey>` `<keyMaterial>`.

Comment: BTW, don't use trailing backwards slashes for directory paths. The backwards slash is a separator, if there's nothing to separate, you mostly don't need it; e.g. `"%SystemRoot%\System32\netsh.exe" WLAN Export Profile Name="MyWiFiName" Folder="%UserProfile%\Desktop" Key="Clear"`

Comment: @Compo RADIUS CERTIFICATE

Comment: The problem with the EAP-PEAP option is, that it does not save the user credentials in the wlan profile itself. The user credentials are safed in an extra eap user data profile. (For programmers: You can add eap user credentials to a profile using the method WlanSetProfileEapXmlUserData() in wlanapi.dll)

Anyone knows how to leverage this dll from management platform or powershell script?